# Unit Testing - Spring Boot App

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

I looked at this link : [How to write a unit test for a Spring Boot Controller endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053974/how-to-i-write-a-unit-test-for-a-spring-boot-controller-endpoint)

I am planning to unit test my Spring Boot Controller. I have pasted a method from my controller below. When I use the approach mentioned in the link above , will the call that I have to **service.verifyAccount(request)** not be made? Are we just testing whether the controller accepts the request in format specified and returns response in format specfied apart from testing the HTTP status codes?

```
@RequestMapping(value ="verifyAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<VerifyAccountResponse> verifyAccount(@RequestBody VerifyAccountRequest request) {

    VerifyAccountResponse response = service.verifyAccount(request);

    return new ResponseEntity<VerifyAccountResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: It depends upon whether you have mocked the service object. If you have not mocked, it would call the service.

Comment: Thanks @notionquest . What is the purpose of MockMvc and if I don't use mock objects , will all my dependencies get injected by using the code (accepted answer) in the other post?

Comment: Maybe this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223490/are-springs-mockmvc-used-for-unit-testing-or-integration-testing is helpful for answering your "what is the purpose of MockMvc" question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write unit test case 
using

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    // Your spring configuration class containing the                            
  @EnableAutoConfiguration
    // annotation
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
    // Makes sure the application starts at a random free port, caches it         throughout
    // all unit tests, and closes it again at the end.
    @IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
    @WebAppConfiguration
```

make sure you configure all your server configuration like port/url

```
 @Value("${local.server.port}")
 private int port;


private String getBaseUrl() {
    return "http://localhost:" + port + "/";
}
```

Then use code mentioned below

```
        protected <T> ResponseEntity<T>  getResponseEntity(final String       
  requestMappingUrl, final Class<T> serviceReturnTypeClass, final Map<String, ?>       
  parametersInOrderOfAppearance) {
    // Make a rest template do do the service call
    final TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
    // Add correct headers, none for this example

    final HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(new       
  HttpHeaders());
    // Do a call the the url
    final ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.exchange(getBaseUrl() +       
  requestMappingUrl, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, serviceReturnTypeClass,       
  parametersInOrderOfAppearance);
    // Return result
    return entity;
    }

@Test
public void getWelcomePage() {
    Map<String, Object> urlVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ResponseEntity<String> response = getResponseEntity("/index",     
    String.class,urlVariables);

    assertTrue(response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK));
}
```